# In emacs stack-ghci cannot load interface files but `stack build` from the command line does

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-stack

I can `stack build` a project from the command line but when I try `C-c C-l` in emacs (with `(custom-set-variables '(haskell-process-type 'stack-ghci))`) I get an error that all the package modules I import can't be found.

```
/home/amcp011/bec/amcp011/accelerate/gpe/src/Numeric/GPE/Utils.hs:30:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Array.Accelerate’
    Locations searched:
      Data/Array/Accelerate.hs
      Data/Array/Accelerate.lhs
      Data/Array/Accelerate.hsig
      Data/Array/Accelerate.lhsig
      /home/amcp011/bec/amcp011/accelerate/gpe/src/Data/Array/Accelerate.hs
      /home/amcp011/bec/amcp011/accelerate/gpe/src/Data/Array/Accelerate.lhs
      /home/amcp011/bec/amcp011/accelerate/gpe/src/Data/Array/Accelerate.hsig
      /home/amcp011/bec/amcp011/accelerate/gpe/src/Data/Array/Accelerate.lhsig
```

`gpe.cabal`:

```
build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                   , bytestring
                   , bytestring-conversion
                   , mtl
                   , time
                   , filepath
                   , directory
                   , accelerate
                   , accelerate-io
```

`stack.yaml`:

```
extra-deps: [accelerate-1.0.0.0
            ,accelerate-io-1.0.0.0
            ]
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a public link to this project? It is tough to debug without an example...

Comment: @Alec: https://github.com/amcphail/gpe  It is not finished, I have uploaded in response to your comment.  I am in the development stage where it is helpful to load files in emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to compile your project with `stack build` (of course, after installing a few system wide dependencies like llvm, cuda, fftw3 etc.) and load it fine with `C-c C-l` in emacs.

Here is the minimal emacs config that worked for me:

```
(defun haskell-mode-setup ()
  (setq haskell-process-type 'stack-ghci))

(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'interactive-haskell-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'haskell-mode-setup)
```

The only ways I was able to replicate the issue you are having was with  `inf-haskell-mode`, instead of `interactive-haskell-mode`, as well as simply by setting 
`(setq haskell-process-type 'ghci)`. So, it is possible that emacs doesn't find `stack`.

I'd recommend trying to let haskell-mode know where stack is, in case that it is installed in a non-common location: `(setq haskell-process-path-stack "/path/to/stack")`.

Alternatively, I've solved a few issues in the past related to `$PATH` environment variable being not the same that is set for the current user, but the one that is used system wide. Simply install `exec-path-from-shell` emacs package and add `(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)` to the `~/.emacs`.

Also, if you haven't done it yet, inspecting haskell-mode log could prove being useful. Add `(setq haskell-process-log t)` to `haskell-mode-setup`, which will result in an extra buffer with the log.

Notes:

- In order to compile your package, I had to remove few lines from `stack.yaml`, namely ones that include local dirs `/home/amcp011/local/`, which are not included in the repo and use my system installed `gcc` instead of one from `RHEL6.3`.
- If you use some other emacs packages besides `haskell-mode`, they might be the cause of the problem as well. I've tested it with `intero` and `flycheck` without any problems.
- Try upgrading to newest `stack upgrade` and `haskell-mode`, maybe that will help. I've tested with `stack-1.5.1` and `haskell-mode-20170824.1124` on `emacs-25.2.2`